# Remove empty values from array simply - javascript

Tags: javascript

I have looked at previous Q/A and I did not find much help there. Mainly as I did not understand what was coded.

I am just looking to remove any empty values in my array.

My simple approach - that is not working!

My code is -

```
var colors = [a, b, c, d, e, f];
var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  if (colors[i] !== 'undefined' || colors[i] !== null || colors[i] !== "") {
    newArray.push(colors[i]);
  }
}
console.log(newArray.length); // == 6 
console.log(newArray) //== yellow,blue,red,,,
```

I would have thought that my if statement would filter all elements with value and push on to my new array. 
I really need newArray length to equal 3 and just hold vales, no empty string `""` should be in the newArray.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "If the color is null **or** if the color is the empty string, include it in the result". No value can be identical to both `null` and `""` at the same time.

Comment: you use || between conditions, so if colors is not undefined you ll insert it (just example). use &&

Comment: which values are supposed to be null or empty? what are you expecting?

Comment: Probably you should just replace || with &&

Comment: You are using the OR boolean operator (||) instead you should be using the AND boolean operator (&&). Have a look at the [MDN page on operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators)

Comment: Am I not saying - if the colour array value is not "undefined" or "null" or "" then pass on to new array??Or am I just confused??

Comment: you are, check my answer. Just think about it. value CAN NOT be undefined, "" and null in the same time. Your if is ALWAYS true.

Comment: Yep, Am confusing my self - Cheers for the help

Comment: What is with the downvotes? You don't vote on OPs experience, you should vote if the question is legit. He has tried, he has failed, he has shown us the codes. His assumption is wrong, which is why he came here in the first place!

Comment: Look at the [implementation of `compact` in Lo-Dash](https://github.com/bestiejs/lodash/blob/v1.2.0/dist/lodash.js#L3014).

Answer (score 4):

use && instead of ||:

```
var colors = ["yellow", "","red", "blue", "", ""];
var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  if (colors[i] !== undefined && colors[i] !== null && colors[i] !== "") {
    newArray.push(colors[i]);
  }
 }
console.log(newArray.length); // == 3 
console.log(newArray) //== yellow,blue,red,,,
```

Comment: I think you mean `colors[i] !== undefined` it should not be `'undefined'` that will make it a string

Answer (score 2):

use && instead of ||:

```
var colors = ["yellow", "","red", "blue", "", ""];
var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  if (colors[i] !== undefined && colors[i] !== null && colors[i] !== "") {
    newArray.push(colors[i]);
  }
 }
console.log(newArray.length); // == 3 
console.log(newArray) //== yellow,blue,red,,,
```

For your use case you could also use

```
for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  if (colors[i]) {
    newArray.push(colors[i]);
  }
 }
```

This will filter out any falsy values.
Falsy values include

```
false
0
""
null
undefined
NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use colors[i] to existence checking,

```
var colors = ["yellow", "","red", "blue", "", "", true, 1];
var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    if (typeof colors[i] == 'string' && colors[i]) {
        newArray.push(colors[i]);
    }
}
console.log(newArray) //["yellow", "red", "blue"]
```

relevant resource [javascript type conversion](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/type-conversion/)

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If 'false' value is important then:

```
var colors = [0,1,'a',,'',null,undefined,false,true];
    colors = colors.filter(function(e){
        return (e===undefined||e===null||e==='')?false:~e;
    });
```

else:

```
var colors = [0,1,'a',,'',null,undefined,false,true];
        colors = colors.filter(function(e){return e;});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var colors = ["yellow", null, "blue", "red", undefined, 0, ""];

// es5:
var newArray = colors.filter(function(e){return !!e;});

// es6:
var newArray = colors.filter((e)=>!!e);

console.log(newArray.length); // ==> 3
console.log(newArray) // ==> ["yellow","blue","red"]
```