# Mysql + json formatting

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

In my node app i am using mysql. I retrieve data from mysql and converting each row to json(working fine).But my requirement i have to print the field with value otherwise don't.

Consider:
My sql result..

```
level0:"xxxxxx"  level1:"fffffff" level3:"btggtgt" level:""
```

Now the json i am getting is:

```
[
{    
level0="xxxxxxx",
level1="fffffff",
level3="btggtgt".
level4=""
}
]
```

But i need the output as:

```
[
    {
    level0="xxxxxxx",
    level1="fffffff",
    level3="btggtgt"    
    }
    ]
```

i have to omit level4 because its value is ""(empty).

My code is:

```
connection.query("select * from levels where level0 = '" + level0 + "' and level1 = '"+level1+"' and level2 = ''", function(err, row1,          fields)    {

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    res.end(JSON.stringify(row1,null,"\n"));

    }); 


var query5result;
    querylevel5(function(result5)
    {
for (var level in result5)
{
console.log("ssssssss="+util.inspect(result5[level]))
  if (result5[level] == null || result5[level] == '')
  {
      delete result5[level];
  }
}
query5result=result5;
```

Comment: store the mysql result in an array then filter it and do as you wish

Comment: in your table, is level "blank" or is it "NULL"

Comment: Thanks @Rafee i think mysql result itself an array..How can i filter and apply json??

Comment: can any level be black randomly?

Comment: yes...... om_deshpande ...

Comment: Can you just try, what i told you.

Comment: @Rafee  i am very new to this node.js concepts and json..So if you guide i can try..I searched a lot for json customize using node.js..i can't find anything..

Comment: Dropping out a random column isn't going to be easy to do with mysql. As @Rafee suggested, it will be better to use one of javascripts array functions to remove the elements with blank value.

Comment: 1. Get the mysql data in array. 
2. Filter the array and remove out the empty values
3. make your filtered array into desired format.


FYI
------------
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164699/remove-empty-values-from-array-simply-javascript

Comment: @om_deshpande I believe, we can do from mysql statement, we just need to write the correct syntax like.

@Subburaj , please take a look at below sql statement


`select abc from table where abc IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Mysql output is an object,how can i convert into an array??

Comment: @Rafee Using your statement the entire row will be ignored just because abc is null. That's not what the OP wants

Comment: @Subburaj There's no need to convert it to an array. in javascript you can access object properties just like an array - object['property']

Comment: run a for-in loop to find and exclude the empty property

Comment: @Subburaj, a quick side-comment, use `where level0 = ?` instead of `where level0 = '" + level0 + "'`. String concatenation is a security hole. mode-mysql will do the escaping for you

Comment: @Richard Marr  if i do that my problem will be solved??

Comment: @Subburaj it doesn't solve the problem you asked about, it solves a different problem, namely that the technique you're currently using is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to loop and delete this empty level

```
connection.query("select * from levels where level0 = '" + level0 + "' and level1 =    '"+level1+"' and level2 = ''", function(err, row1,          fields)    {
for (var level in row1)
{
  if (row1[level] == null || row1[level] == "")
  {
      delete row1[level];
  }
}
)};
//...then go on:
res.end(JSON.stringify(row1,null,"\n"));
```

Comment: you already had queryed the rows in the first line or not?
so look in my edit